# Iterating over files, splitting by pattern

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to wrap my head around file stream processing. Got input looking like this:

```
bla
blubb

blubber
testcode
```

There's several files all looking like the above. Right now, I'm using a single file approach that reads the whole file into memory and splits it:

```
Files.newBufferedReader("myfile").use { f ->
    f.readText().splitToSequence("\n\n").forEach {
        // do my stuff
    }
}
```

Now, I'm trying to generalize this to larger inputs (making it impractical to hold the file in memory) and several files. Ideally, I'd treat a whole directory of input files as a single stream of lines I split on `\n\n` and work on the parts. How would I do this?

Comment: For the record, while Ilia's answer solves the difficult Kotlin part, I've solved the "treat a directory of files as a stream of lines" with `InputStreamReader(SequenceInputStream(com.google.common.collect.Iterators.asEnumeration(Files.list("myDir").map { Files.newInputStream(it) }.iterator())), Charsets.US_ASCII).useLines { ... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read file as a sequence of text lines and then regroup those lines taking empty line as a delimiter:

```
File("myfile").useLines { lines ->
    val lineBlocks: Sequence<List<String>> = buildSequence {
        val block = mutableListOf<String>()
        for (line in lines) {
            when {
                line.isNotEmpty() -> block.add(line)
                block.isNotEmpty() -> {
                    yield(block.toList())
                    block.clear()
                }
            }
        }
        if (block.isNotEmpty()) yield(block.toList())
    }

    lineBlocks.forEach {
        println(it.joinToString())
    }
}
```

Here you get the result in `lineBlocks`, which is a sequence where each element is a list of lines in a single block.

Comment: Go coroutines! And thanks for the clever application of `when`.